What was it that Wittgenstein found funny here?
Wittgenstein's Über Gewißheit (On Certainty) starts with the remark

Wenn du weißt, daß hier eine Hand ist, so geben wir dir alles übrige zu.
(Sagt man, der und der Satz lasse sich nicht beweisen, so heißt das natürlich nicht, daß er sich nicht aus andern herleiten läßt; jeder Satz läßt sich aus andern herleiten. Aber diese mögen nicht sicherer sein als er selbst.) (Dazu eine komische Bemerkung H. Newmans.)


If you know that there is a hand here, we'll grant you all the rest.
(When one says that this and that sentence cannot be proved, then this of course doesn't mean that it cannot be inferred from others; every sentence can be inferred from others. But those might not be more certain than the original one.)(See about this a comical remark by H. Newman.)

[my translation]
This refers to Moore's (in)famous proof of an external world (Here is One Hand). But what was the comical comment by Newman? It seems pretty clear that the last sentence refers to cardinal Newman's An Essay in Aid of a Grammar of Assent, which Wittgenstein must have read (and which may have inspired some of his criticisms; the previous remark about 'inference' also implicitly references that essay), but which specific comical remark in that book did (or could) this refer to? What was the joke? (Does Über Gewißheit 554 perhaps give a clue? If you have an answer, how sure are you?)

I don't think - unless there is other evidence (letters or memoirs by others) we'll ever really know, but we should be able to wittle down the likely candidates based on the text.

Maybe it's the Killer Joke and you are not meant to find it?

@ScottRowe Well, Wittgenstein did believe that even in a universe without any people ethics would still be valid (even if it's unsayable). (See Diaries, 2.8.16). So, it should be fine to reveal the Killer Joke. Ethics will still be valid after we've all croaked.
